# google server-to-server authenticated request returns forbidden 403

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

i authenticated a simple get 
request to the Core Reporting API by using a service account. But the response is always:

```
{"error":{"errors": [{"message":"Forbidden"}],"code":403,"message":"Forbidden"}}
```

When i authenticate the same api request via "Client ID for web 
applications" (OAuth 2.0 Playground) i get the api response without problems. So the problem is not in the api query.

This is what i did:

1. i logged in at the google api console with an account wich has 
   access to the analytics account
2. there i created a new service account within a project wich has access to 
   the analytics api
3. with the latest google-api-php-client i authenticated the request 
   to the analytics api by using this service account. The authentication 
   seems to work fine, as the request header contains `authorization: 
   Bearer {access_token}`. But i get always a 403.

Here is a short code snippet of what iam doing:

```
$client = new apiClient(); 
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new apiAssertionCredentials( 
    '{my_service_account_email}', 
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'), 
    '{my_service_account_certificate}' 
));
$request = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest(new apiHttpRequest('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?{my_query}'));
```

What iam doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer on google groups:

> Unfortunately Service Accounts aren't supported by all Google APIs. We're working to enable it more broadly.

https://groups.google.com/group/oauth2-dev/browse_thread/thread/3414283abb5c0ba0

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful for those who are still seeking answer

you need to connect your client_id into your Google Analytics account, some illustrated instructions can be found at http://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Setup+Google+Analytics+Reporting+with+OAuth2+Service+Accounts+(since+1.4.6)